# What's the cause of this "Unexected token" JavaScript error?

Tags: ajax

Just did a fresh install of CiviCRM 4.6.5 on Drupal 7.38 and the JQuery/Ajax isn't working. I get the following 2 errors in the Chrome Developer Console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  en_US?r=7WtZJ:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  XrTF2AAu:1
```

I have gone through the "Troubleshooting popups, autocompletes, or other javascript problems" document and have verified everything and cleared my Drupal cache.

Comment: Take a look at your page source - possibly there is a malformed script tag on the page. Search the page source for en_US? and it should find a script tag -- what does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

This an old thread, but I just encountered the same problem. In case anyone else lands here, here's what I found:

The issue was that I had a typo in the domain for the URL settings, which I'd defined in civicrm.settings.php. My super-helpful ISP redirects the request to http://searchassist.verizon.com/main?a-bunch-of-params-including-my-typoed-domain. That URL contains HTML, of course, not JavaScript. When the browser gets back HTML from a script src, it throws a parse error.

Comment: To echo this point: I just encountered this on a WordPress site which was redirecting all 404s to the home page. Under System Settings > Resource URLs, I had a bad value for "Image Upload URL", leading to 404s (and thus returned HTML) for at least some Angular.js scripts.